# How to test if a cell conforms to the rules defined in ConditionalFormattingRule with POI?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I try to use POI to convert excel to HTML,but there are have some Conditional Formatting in my excel.These conditional formats affect the background color of the cell.I used following code to get all conditional formats.

```java
            Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(i);

            // get conditional formatting in the sheet
            SheetConditionalFormatting formatting = sheet.getSheetConditionalFormatting();

            // number of Conditional Formattings
            int formattingsNum = formatting.getNumConditionalFormattings();

            if (formattingsNum != 0){

                // get all conditional formatting
                for (int j = 0; j < formattingsNum; j++) {

                    ConditionalFormatting conditionalFormatting = formatting.getConditionalFormattingAt(j);

                }
            }
```

Now I want to determine whether a cell meets the rules in the conditional format.I've tried multiple variations of this, but none of them seem to work. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

That's a challenging task. A cell might have multiple conditional formatting rules applied. And there are at least two kinds of conditional formatting rules affecting the background color of the cell. That are pattern formatting and color scale formatting.

`Apache poi` provides [ConditionalFormattingEvaluator](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/formula/ConditionalFormattingEvaluator.html) which has a method [getConditionalFormattingForCell](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/formula/ConditionalFormattingEvaluator.html#getConditionalFormattingForCell-org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell-) to get all conditional formatting for cell if the cell  fulfills the rule's criterion. Using that we can get all matching conditional formatting for a cell. Having those we then have to check whether there are pattern formatting and/or color scale formatting. For pattern formatting we can get  the background color set. But for color scale formatting the next challenge is evaluating the thresholds.

Example working draft:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;

import java.io.FileInputStream;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ExcelGetConditionalFormattingFromConditionalFormattingEvaluator {

 static List<EvaluationConditionalFormatRule> getMatchingConditionalFormattingForCell(Cell cell) {
  Sheet sheet = cell.getSheet(); 
  Workbook workbook = sheet.getWorkbook();
  WorkbookEvaluatorProvider workbookEvaluatorProvider =
   (WorkbookEvaluatorProvider)workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
  ConditionalFormattingEvaluator conditionalFormattingEvaluator = 
   new ConditionalFormattingEvaluator(workbook, workbookEvaluatorProvider);
  List<EvaluationConditionalFormatRule> matchingCFRulesForCell = 
   conditionalFormattingEvaluator.getConditionalFormattingForCell(cell);
  return matchingCFRulesForCell;
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  //String filePath = "ExcelHavingConditionalFormatting.xls";
  String filePath = "ExcelHavingConditionalFormatting.xlsx";

  Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(filePath));
  Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

  for (Row row : sheet) {
   for (Cell cell : row) {
    System.out.println(cell.getAddress());
    List<EvaluationConditionalFormatRule> matchingCFRules = getMatchingConditionalFormattingForCell(cell);
    System.out.println(matchingCFRules);
    for (EvaluationConditionalFormatRule evalCFRule : matchingCFRules) {
     ConditionalFormattingRule cFRule = evalCFRule.getRule();
     if (cFRule.getPatternFormatting() != null) {
      PatternFormatting patternFormatting = cFRule.getPatternFormatting();
      System.out.println("has pattern formatting: " + patternFormatting);
      System.out.println(patternFormatting.getFillBackgroundColorColor()); 
     } else if (cFRule.getColorScaleFormatting() != null) {
      System.out.println("has color scale formatting: " + cFRule.getColorScaleFormatting());
     }
    }  

    System.out.println();   
   }
  }

  workbook.close();
 }
}
```

Additional challenge is when there are multiple rules having pattern formatting and/or color scale formatting applied to a cell. Then we additional have to check the rule's [priority](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/ConditionalFormattingRule.html#getPriority--). The priority also is taken into account by [ConditionalFormattingEvaluator.getConditionalFormattingForCell](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/formula/ConditionalFormattingEvaluator.html#getConditionalFormattingForCell-org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell-). So the order in the returned `List<EvaluationConditionalFormatRule>` represents the priority.

Comment: it's a promising solution! Successfully solved my problem,thank you for your answer sincerely.

Comment: I have a doubt.Why not directly return conditionalFormattingEvaluator.getConditionalFormattingForCell (cell), use a redundant loop, use getMatchingCells to get all the cells, and then determine whether the current cell is in.This looks like a redundant operation

Comment: @jiangyongbing24: You are correct. I had misinterpret `getConditionalFormattingForCell` method. I had thougt it returns all conditional formatting applied to the cell independent of if the rule matches. But "This checks all applicable ConditionalFormattingRules for the cell's sheet, in defined "priority" order, returning the matches if any." I have updated my answer.